# Publish to a core database

Tags: azure, scaling, solution-architecture

When implementing multiple regions/clusters,  sitecore documentation states that each cluster must have its own core database.(https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/clustering-and-geographic-distribution.html)

> Each cluster has its own dedicated core database - core databases
>   cannot be replicated and must be managed per cluster

How do you keep core dbs synced? One of the options we are looking at is to publish from CM server. We tested locally by adding core references in configuration files and a publishing target in core db. It seems to work fine at first sight. Is there any danger in publishing from one core to others?

Answer (score 5):

We have always used database-level replication to keep core databases in sync.

I don't have experience doing this with publishing, but I have a couple concerns. These are things that happen when an item is published that you may not want for core databases:

1. You will lose version history of the items on the destination core database since publishing only keeps one version
2. Unless you customize it, the HTML cache (presentation cache) will be cleared with each publish, even though you're not publishing content
3. Any other custom `publish:end` or `publish:end:remote` event handlers you've registered for your application

Comment: I thought db replication wasn't support by sitecore

Comment: Technically that's true, but it's worked well for us.

Comment: We also use DB replication.  We have been using since we first launched our site on Sitecore over 2 years ago.  We have not had any issues.